# Moto G6 not charging, not connecting via USB and battery indicator frozen at zero, not enetering battery saving mode

Tags: recovery-mode, usb, charging

Here is how problem came about:

I unlocked my moto G6's bootloader and fastboot flashed twrp-3.4.0-0-ali.img in it. I opened TWRP trough the recovery option in fastboot, and enetered my PIN, but TWRP was unable to decrypt my storage. I noticed that TWRP was showing that the CPU temperature was at 34ºC and battery full. Then, I clickend on "cancel" the operation, kept TWRP read only and rebooted to delete the fingerprint recognition in system settings, which I thought could have been causing the failure of TWRP to decrypt. That didn't work, but this time I shut my phone down with power button. I am unsure if I did so before or after cancelling the operation, but I didn't choose the option to keep TWRP read only. I also noticed TWRP showing a ridiculously high CPU temperature before turning off. Regardless, it disappeared. I can now boot normally but I am having the issues described in the title. I tried a factory reset from moto but it solve this problem.

I performed a full adb backup before unlocking the bootloader with the command

> adb backup -apk -shared -all -f C:\Users\

However, I may not be able to restore this backup via USB, given that my phone is not connecting via USB.

Any ideas of what to try?

Answer (score 0):

After factor resetting through fastboot (so called hard reset), rather than factor resetting through the settings (i.e. soft reset), I got my phone in order again.